# Firebase trigger onUpdate returning an error after update

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

After updating to the lastest Firebase functions "firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
 ,"firebase-functions": "^1.0.1 and Firebase tools 3.18.4, I have the following error message with the database trigger complaining of the property 'key' as undefined, how to fix this code

// this is the cloud function

```
exports.OnBalanceChange = functions.database.ref('/balance/{userID}')
  .onUpdate(event => {
    var userid = event.data.key;
    var eventSnapshot = event.data;
    console.log("user ID is", userid);

        return 0;


  });



TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at exports.OnBalanceChange.functions.database.ref.onUpdate.event (/user_code/index.js:760:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please study the migration guide for the 1.0 version of Cloud Functions for Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Specifically, see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database).  You'll see that the single argument to onUpdate was converted to two arguments, and the types of the arguments have changed.  You can now use `change.before.key` (assuming that the first arg is now `change` to get the id of the document that changed.

Comment: Thank you I fixed the issue.